# Generation a txt using VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, header, row, txt

I have a Excel spreadsheet and I need to generate a txt after applying a filter. My code is:

```
Sub gsCriarArquivoTxt()
    On Error GoTo TratarErro
    
    Dim lsCaminho As String
    Dim llArquivo As Long
    Dim lLinha As String
    Dim lContador As Long
    Dim iTotalLinhas As Long
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    'txt file name
    lsCaminho = InputBox("Caminho e nome do arquivo:", "Caminho do arquivo...", actName)
    
    If Dir(lsCaminho) = "" Then
        llArquivo = FreeFile
        Open lsCaminho For Output As #llArquivo
        
        iTotalLinhas = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        lContador = 1
                           
        While lContador <= iTotalLinhas
        'Print the data in the file
        Print #llArquivo, Cells(lContador, 1) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 2) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 3) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 4) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 5) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 6) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 7) & "," & _
                            Cells(lContador, 8)
        
        lContador = lContador + 1
        Wend
        
        MsgBox "File saved in: " & lsCaminho
        
        Close #llArquivo
        
    Else
    MsgBox "File already exists!"
    End If
    
    
    
Sair:
    Exit Sub
TratarErro:
    MsgBox "There was an error generating the file " & Err.Description & " - " & Err.Number
    GoTo Sair
    
End Sub
```

My code read and write rows and colums but not find o first row after the header. I have ther error:
"There was an error generating the file incompatible types 13"

Comment: *My code read and write rows and colums but not find o first row after the header* ... there is nothing in your code at all that would find or skip header rows.

Comment: Use [`Option Explicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/option-explicit-statement) in your VBA coding and make sure all your variables are correctly declared. Then switch your error handling off and find which line is causing the error.